# При смене языка теряются get параметры, как исправить?

Tags: php, mysql

Структура переключения через get

```
<div class="lang">
        <a href="<?php echo $uri ?>lang=ru" class="active-lang">Русский</a>
        <a href="<?php echo $uri ?>lang=en">English</a>
     </div>
```

в базе есть 2 таблицы с окончаниями в названиях _ru и _en переключение идет таким образом, если вкратце,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stores_".$_SESSION['lang']);
подставляется блок .$_SESSION['lang'].
```

Если говорить о страницах типа `about.php?lang=en` то переключение идет нормально. 
А если говорить о таких ссылках `/shop.php?type=stores&id=25&lang=en` то при нажатие на переключение языка там идет ссылка `shop.php?lang=en без type=stores&id=25` что не правильно и приводит в ошибке на странице. 
Я использовал такое `echo substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, -8);` что бы узнать url и обрезал лишнее так как в url была 2 раза написала lang=en или lang=ru но это приводит к проблемам на страницах типа `about.php?lang=en` (обрезает лишнее).
Вообщем мне кажется это костыль. Как сделать так что бы переключение было нормальное? Думаю вы поняли о чем я. При условии что смена языка будет через get параметры т.е. как у меня сейчас.

Здесь я пытаюсь подставить в зависимости от страницы ? и & а также обрезать лишние символы. При таком коде страницы типа `/shop.php?type=stores&id=25&lang=en` работают и если я нахожусь в корне сайта то тоже все работает но если я нахожусь на index.php то там срабатывает обрезка символом почему то. Но если добавить в `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || 'index.php')` то на главной все работает но ссылки типа `/shop.php?type=stores&id=25&lang=en` перестают работать.

```
$var1 = "?";
$var2 = "&";

$uri = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
    $uri = $var1;
}
 else {
    $uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, -8).$var2;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно концепцию поменять. Пускай язык где-то в одном месте меняется и ко всему сайту применяется и не нужно будет заморачиваться с такими ссылками.

Comment: На ютюбе нашел пока только такую концепцию, как по другому сделать пока не знаю.

Comment: Погуглите про локализацию сайта еще, почитайте статьи. Лучше на этапе проектирования дольше посидеть чем потом заплатки к коду латать и выдумать всяческие изощрения в проекте.

Comment: Используйте куки для сохранения выбранного языка. Не надо так мучаться с повтором get-параметров. Вот один из миллиона доступных примеров: https://php.ru/forum/threads/ne-mogu-sobrat-kod-dlja-lokalizacii-sajta.51855/#post-414898

Comment: Да, вроде неплохой пример. Но здесь берется перевод с файла, это мне тоже нужно, но у меня большинство данных в БД. Как в данном примере вытащить ее?

Answer (score 0):

`substr()` - не лучшая функция для вашей ситуации. Приведу пример. Что, если параметр с языком не будет последним в списке? Или его вобще не будет. Потеряем данные.

Как вариант - сделать массива параметров из get и использовать implode для всех параметров.

```
$page_origin = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] )[0];
$page_params = array();

foreach( $_GET as $param => $param_value ){
    $page_params[] = "{$param}={$param_value}";
}

$page_params = implode( '&', $page_params );
$uri = "{$page_origin}?{$page_params}";
```

Еще можно сделать проверку на то, задан ли уже язык, и если задан, менять значение или удалять его

Удаляем параметр:

```
if( isset( $_GET['lang'] ){
    unset( $_GET['lang'] );
}
```

Меняем его значение:

```
if( isset( $_GET['lang'] ){
    $_GET['lang'] = 'ru';
}
```